# Bug in alternating subtitles with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, subtitle

I wrote a jquery script to play short videoclips with random audio fragments + subtitles attached. See [here](http://luukschroder.nl/rearrangements) for a 'working' example. Most of the code is triggered when the video ends, and that part works well. However I have an occasional problem with the on document.ready function. It works about 7 out of 8 times, but sometimes a 404 is given for the .vtt subtitle file and the first video plays without subtitle (I checked the link and the .vtt file is actually created). (you can recreate the bug by refreshing the page a few times) I was wondering if someone has a suggestion on how to fix or debug this... Thank you!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        createsubtitle(); //creates random subtitle string
        timestamp0 = $.now();// two timestamps to make unique files (to be deleted afterwards)
        timestamp1 = $.now();
        window.timestamp0 = timestamp0
        window.timestamp1 = timestamp1
        $.ajax({type: "POST",url:"save1.php",data: {text:subtitle, time:timestamp1},success: function() {console.log("message sent!")}}); // first .vtt file is made using php (see code below)
        createsubtitle(); // new random subtitle
        $.ajax({type: "POST",url:"save0.php",data: {text:subtitle, time:timestamp0},success: function() {console.log("message sent!")}}); //  second php (the script alternates between two .vtt files)
        $("#subtitles").attr("src", "subtitle/sub1" + timestamp1 + ".vtt"); // one .vtt file is added as src to track element #subtitles
        $('#rearrangements').get(0).play(); // video is played
});
```

php code:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$subtitle = $_POST['text'];
$timestamp = $_POST['time'];
$filename = 'subtitle/sub1'.$timestamp.'.vtt';
$myfile = fopen($filename, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = $subtitle;
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```